# Why is IK hand bone in the wrong direction during follow path?

Tags: bones, bone.constraints

This is my first time but I'm trying to use the Follow path constraint but as soon as I assign all the bones of my character to the NurbsPath one of his arms bends backwards because the IK control bone is far away.[image]

Comment: can u please elaborate what do you want to achieve by assigning all bones to a path? makes no sense for me...."normally" you would make 1 bone to follow path...and a hint: you will attract far more people to your question by providing blendf file, if you don't provide all important settings.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve this kind of issues is to create an empty, make it follow the path and then set a "child of" bone constraint from the IK hand to the empty (you can even animate the influence slider of the bone constraint).